# Laravel `Storage::put()` not working on Unix server

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I want to save my images that modified by [image intervention](https://image.intervention.io/v2) in storage folder in my Laravel project.

`Storage::put()` this works fine and saves images in `storage` folder (my local OS is windows 10), but not working in server OS(CentOS 8).
`storage` folder permissions is 755 i've tried 777 but not worked too.
Here is my code:

```
$filename = basename($request->tutorialImage);
$image = Image::make($request->tutorialImage)->resize(300, 400);
$image->stream();
Storage::disk('local')->put('files/shares/resizedImages/' . $filename . '-' . 300 . '-' . 400. '.jpg', $image);
```

I've already ran command `php artisan storage:link` too.

Comment: Make sure the directory/file names are exactly the same as on the disk, Windows is not case sensitive - linux is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
chown -R $USER:www-data bootstrap/cache
chown -R $USER:www-data storage
chown -R $USER:www-data resources/views
chown -R $USER:www-data public/files

chmod -R 775 storage
chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
chmod -R 775 resources/views
chmod -R 775 public/files
```